# Slide in animation when updating screen on android

Tags: android

I'm trying to do something in android, and I'm not sure how.

I have this `ListView`, which I update with new info from time to time, and I would like it if I could have a transition effect when the new data is in, like the "Slide from the left" affect that I get when calling in a new activity.

but I'd rather not open a new activity for each new peace of data, as that way I would end up with a lot of activities.

Is there a way that I can emulate this slide from the left effect?